# How to create a For Loop for a varying range per project using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have weekly tasks where I will receive a .xlsx file with standardized headers, however the data itself varies. The relevant headers are:

A - Loan Number, B - Mortgagor First Name, C - Mortgagor Last Name, D - Mortgagor Birth Date

I have set up my macro to perform some of the initial manual steps which is to insert a header into Column E and give it an assigned name, set up a filter across my headers, filter out mortgagors without a populated first name (Column B) and filter to display only the blank cells in Column D (So I would be looking at mortgagors who do not have a DOB mapped). The issue I am having is figuring out how to set up a For Loop, or whatever is the optimal conditional statement, that will populate the word 'BLANK' into Column E for each empty cell in Column D for all cells in Column B with a populated name. Since the data varies, I do not want to hard code a range.

| Loan Number | First Name | Last Name | Birth Date | Birth Date Blanks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ------------- | ------------ | ----------- | ------------ | ------------------- |
| xxxxxxxxxx | Sam | Adams | 01/01/1999 |  |
| xxxxxxxxxx | Jack | Daniels | 02/02/1999 |  |
| xxxxxxxxxx | Jose | Cuervo |  |  |

So in the above table, I would need my macro to only display Jose Cuervo and the like, and to automatically populate 'BLANK' into Column E for every name that is shown in Column B.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you'd like to first determine the number of rows (number of loans) then check if there's a first name, then check if there's a birth date. If there IS a first name, but NOT a birth date, then you'd like column E to say blank. This code should do that if I'm understanding correctly:

```
Sub filter()

Dim numberOfLoans As Integer
Dim row As Integer

'This finds the number of loans (assuming there's no missing
'loan numbers and the first row is the header)

Cells(1, 1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
numberOfLoans = ActiveCell.row - 1

'This for loops says that if Column B has a name, but Column D
'empty, then Column E will say "Blank"

For row = 1 To numberOfLoans

If Cells(row + 1, 2) <> "" And Cells(row + 1, 4) = "" Then
    Cells(row + 1, 5) = "Blank"
End If

Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Dan, thank you very much for the response. The code you provided worked exactly as intended! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Would you mind pressing the checkmark next to my answer underneath the upvote/downvote if you have a chance?